# How does Perl access POST parameters when SSL is used?

Tags: perl, ssl

I have a generic html form that pass parameters to a Perl script and it retrieves the values and formats them. SSL was recently implemented, and now the parameters are no longer being passed to, or perhaps in a format that the Perl script can interpret. How does Perl access POST parameters when SSL is used?

sample fields//

```
    <form action="script.pl" method="post">

    Enter the initial year (1800-2008): 
    <input name="first" id="first" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4">

    Enter the final year (1800-2008):
    <input name="final" id="final" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="2007">
<input name"submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sample perl//

```
require 'cgi-lib.pl';
First: $in{'first'}
Final: $in{'final'}
;
exit;
```

Comment: SSL has no effect on this. Something else also changed.

Comment: hmm, guess it is back to the drawing board as the script is still the same. :\ Thanks for the reply!

Comment: cgi-lib.pl? Is it 1996?

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma Perl 4 is making a comeback!